# How to find evaluate this infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I obtained this series as the one which describes an integral I'm trying to calculate from the definition

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{4n}{(2n+2k+1)^2}$$

From plugging in values of $n$ it looks like this converges to $\frac 12$.

Can you guys give me a hint as to how to show this?

Comment: Try to rewrite it so that you recognise a Riemann sum.

Comment: That's not an infinite series as the terms of your sum depend on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{4n}{(2n+2k+1)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{4n^2}{(2n+2k+1)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2n+2k+1}{2n}\right)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0} h \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1+hk+\frac{h}{2})^2}$$
$$=\int^{1}_{0} \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} $$
$$=\left[-\frac{1}{1+x}\right]^1_0$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Darn.  I was so close.  Thanks for the answer!  I'll accept in a couple minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{4n}{(2n+2k+1)^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{4n}{4n^2\left(1+\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\left(\frac{k}{n}+1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2}$$
let $\frac{k}{n}=u\implies \frac{1}{n}=du\to  0$

Upper limit at $k=n-1$ $\implies u=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{k}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n}=1$
Lower limit at $k=1$ $\implies u=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{k}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$
using integration, with proper limits 
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\left(\frac{k}{n}+1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\left(u+1\right)^2}$$
$$=\left(\frac{-1}{u+1}\right)_{0}^{1}$$
$$=\left(\frac{-1}{1+1}+\frac{1}{0+1}\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$$